# Clean up spaces between letters / triple spaces in text string

Tags: php, javascript

I need to clean up strings of text where every letter has a space in between and every space is composed of 3 spaces, for example:

```
E X C E P T I O N A L   C R E A T I V I T Y   A N D   A  
T A I L O R E D   D E S I G N   E D G E
```

How would I go about cleaning the text up, ie - converting every triple-space to a single space, and removing the space in between each letter?

Client-side / server side solutions welcome.

Comment: broadly speaking, you'll likely end up using regular expressions for this.

Comment: though (thinking out loud) you could do a find and replace model. Search for all triple spaces, replace with a dash. Then find all spaces and remove them. Then find all dashes and replace that with a single space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/(.) /', '\\1', $string);
```

The regex engine doesn't match substrings that are the result of a replacement, so it will correctly handle triple spaces without needing to special case them.

Comment: Double spaces, yes. Triple, yes. Odd numbers of spaces, yes. Even numbers greater than two, **no**.

Comment: @Sammitch I presume that the OP's string was originally generated by taking a normal string and adding a space after every character. If that is true then there would never be an even number of spaces.

Comment: Actually my client wanted to increase her letter-spacing, so she added a space between every letter ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
str_replace(array('   ', ' ', '%'), array('%', '', ' '), $text);
```

Just replace % with a character or a string which does not appear in your text.

Comment: Amazing! +1 Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: Awesome. This is how I would've done it before I saw John's note, thanks.

Comment: The problem with this is you always have to ensure that the placeholder character does not occur in the input text. Situations like that end up in a potentially endless search for placeholders of placeholders...

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = <<<_EOI_
E X C E P T I O N A L   C R E A T I V I T Y   A N D   A  
T A I L O R E D   D E S I G N   E D G E
_EOI_;

$patterns = array('/(\w) /', '/ {2,}/');
$replaces = array('$1', ' ');

preg_replace($patterns, $replaces, $input);

// output: 
// EXCEPTIONAL CREATIVITY AND A
// TAILORED DESIGN EDGE
```